# Use OPTIONAL in SPARQL CONSTRUCT query

Tags: graph, sparql, rdf, turtle-rdf

I'm trying to create a graph with all the related predicates and objects. To illustrate, I have the instance ex:First_Civil_War and now I want all predicates and objects to be shown in the graph. I have done this in the following way.

```
construct { 
} where { 
    ex:Fourth_Conquest_of_Gaul ?p ?o
} limit 100
```

However, I want to exclude some of the predicates, for example ex:hasActor. How would I go about this, as the OPTIONAL statement does not work within a CONSTRUCT query.

Comment: why does `OPTIONAL` not work? You can put any SPARQL query into the `WHERE` part. I also don't see how `OPTIONAL` is used to exclude triples, that would be more the task of a `FILTER`

Comment: There is nothing in the template part `CONSTRUCT {}` so it returns the empty graph. Put in the triple patterns you want returned - but not the word OPTIONAL. You can add triple patterns with variables used in an OPTIONAL clause in the WHERE part. The triple template is skipped if a variable is unbound.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> construct { 
> } where { 
>    ex:Fourth_Conquest_of_Gaul ?p ?o
> } limit 100
> ```
>
> However, I want to exclude some of the predicates, for example ex:hasActor. How would I go about this, as the OPTIONAL statement does not work within a CONSTRUCT query.

As noted in the comments, you have an empty template (`construct {} where...`), but you're probably looking for a plain `construct where { ...`.  If you're looking to filter out certain values of `?p`, you can use `FILTER` in the `where` part.  E.g.:

```
construct where {
  ex:Fourth_Conquest_of_Gaul ?p ?o
  filter ( ?p != ex:hasActor )
} limit 100
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, you have an empty template (construct {} where...), but you're probably looking for a plain construct where { .... If you're looking to filter out certain values of ?p, you can use FILTER in the where part. E.g.:

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).